# How to use localstorage for multiple text field?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want use localstorage on my page but what i want is there should be different values on each text field on my page is it possible if yes how??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you want store values present in multiple text fields in local storage, you can definitely do that. Use

```
localStorage.setItem("field1","value1");
localStorage.setItem("field2","value2");
....
```

Regards
Ganesh

Comment: thanks ganesh for replay ,
I want to strore values present in multiple text field in local storage 
i will try it.....